# DefaultCamelContext.getRoutes() is empty so ExchangeHelper.isStreamCachingEnabled throws NullPointerException?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and have tried stepping through this multiple times and can't find a solution.

I have seven routes configured, and when my service starts, these appear to be starting up correctly.

```
DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Total 7 routes, of which 7 are started
DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Apache Camel 2.20.2 ...
```

However, when I send a message along one of the routes, it gets to a `DataFormatter` as a result of a `marshal()` processor, and here a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

If I drill into this, it appears that the issue is with the following code on line 693 of `ExchangeHelper.isStreamCachingEnabled(Exchange)`:

```
return exchange.getContext().getRoute(exchange.getFromRouteId()).getRouteContext().isStreamCaching();
```

At this point:

`exchange.getFromRouteId()` returns a valid route name, the String `"route1"`
`exchange.getContext().getRoute(exchange.getFromRouteId())` returns `null`
`exchange.getContext().getRoutes()` returns an empty list

I'm stumped.

Comment: From where does your route start from eg what is the from uri

Comment: I am trying to use the websocket component to service a request/response RPC protocol.

Comment: I am using the Java DSL and the error occurs when I try to marshal the message back into it's binary form to send back to the caller.

Is there an Apache Camel IRC channel or similar and I can share the details?

Comment: Yeah try tomorrow at either gitter or irc chat - see http://camel.apache.org/irc-room.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in camel-core. I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12348

But it would be good to hear more about how you got this NPE in the first place if you can tell more about your Camel applications. Are you using routes at all, and if so which route did it start from and what component does it use.